# How can one add constraints on existing tables via JPA / Hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using a Postgresql database with JPA / Hibernate. When I'm adding a constraint to a column, i.e. "nullable=false", the database column is not altered to reflect this. Deleting the table and rerunning the application does the job.

Can this be achieved with JPA/Hibernate - mechanisms only WITHOUT deleting entries or the table? Like "Try to alter the table and refuse to do so on inconsistent data"? In my application.properties, I've set

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Any other setting seems to be deleting data and/or tables.

A working solution would be to run an ALTER TABLE script and adding a constraint annotation accordingly, but I'm not really fond of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is impossible to add constraints to the existing table. Think wide about it - what if the data in the table is not satisfied with the constraint? You will get the whole application crash. So Hibernate not even trying to apply the potential harmful operation.

In general, there is the wrong way to manage database schema with hibernate. Auto-generation schema is appropriate for learning or MVP purposes but not for production. Also, SQL migration is a bad idea for many reasons. You should use a special tool for schema management: [liquibase](https://liquibase.org/) (better for me) or [flywaydb](https://flywaydb.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. You're right, of course, as even the hibernate documentation is saying not to use auto-generation for production. Liquibase, together with both maven and hibernate plugin, even offers the possibility to perform a diff on an existing db-schema and an altered entity-model, so i can get what i want. https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app (in case someone else stumbles upon this question).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you mean.
I had to do something similar, add a new column with constraints to a table with existing data.
What I did:

1. Create the column with the constraint and set a temporary `defaultValue`

```
    <addColumn tableName="tableName" schemaName="public">
        <column name="columnName" type="varchar" defaultValue="">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
```

2. Update the necessary data for all rows in the new column, so the constraint is met
3. Drop the `defaultValue` from the new column using `<dropDefaultValue tableName="tableName" columnName="colName" />`